# Save a opencv image with annotations

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I think this is a pretty basic question, but I could not find a answer that works.

I am writing a code to measure grain size of microstructures using opencv in python and I need to draw circles and lines over an image. Here is the code so far:

```
d_ref = min(dh,dv)
cor_linha = (255,0,0)
esp_linha = 1

l1 = cv2.line(corte_imagem,(int(dh/2+0.9*d_ref/2),int(dv/2-0.9*d_ref/2)),(int(dh/2-0.9*d_ref/2),int(dv/2+0.9*d_ref/2)),cor_linha,esp_linha)
l2 = cv2.line(corte_imagem,(int(dh/2-0.9*d_ref/2),int(dv/2-0.9*d_ref/2)),(int(dh/2+0.9*d_ref/2),int(dv/2+0.9*d_ref/2)),cor_linha,esp_linha)
cv2.circle(corte_imagem,(int(dh/2),int(dv/2)),int(0.9*d_ref/2),cor_linha,esp_linha)
cv2.circle(corte_imagem,(int(dh/2),int(dv/2)),int(0.9*d_ref/3),cor_linha,esp_linha)
cv2.circle(corte_imagem,(int(dh/2),int(dv/2)),int(0.9*d_ref/6),cor_linha,esp_linha)
cv2.imshow('imagem',cv2.cvtColor(corte_imagem, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))

cv2.waitKey(0)
for i in range(8):
    cv2.destoryAllWindows()
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

My question is kinda simple: how can I save the image in opencv (or other library) with the annotations (lines and circles)?

Thanks in advance.

BR

Comment: have you tried with `imwrite`?

Comment: It worked pretty well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cv2.imwrite(filename, img)` to save your edited image to your pc.

In your case `cv2.imwrite("new_Image", corte_imagem)`.

Comment: It worked pretty well. Thank you!

Comment: @LeonardoAraujo Great! If you can, I would like to get the confirmation answer with the "V" sign button next to my answer (on the left) and maybe vote up too, I wasn't sure if you know about that.